# spaCy erroring out with I load en_core_web_sm/md/lg

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, entry-point

I have been trying to teach myself spaCy over the last few weeks, and have run into an unexpected error. One of my first lines of code, `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` seems to have stopped working, but only on my PC. It still works fine on my laptop, but my laptop runs the code like 10 times slower, which is not ideal.

When I try to run the code, I get a long error message ending with
`AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'`
When I Google this error message, it talks about version errors, but spaCy seems to be in the same version on both computers and when I changed my PC's Python version to match that of the laptop, it made no difference.

I'm at a loss here and would really appreciate some advice.